# Clang diagnostic flag with '#' causes a build error

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, clang++, compiler-options

In my cmake file I need to add a clang diagnostic flag that includes a `#`, as seen in clang docs for [diagnostic flags](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#diagnostic-flags).

However `cmake` interprets `#` as a remark and fails.

For example:

```
add_definitions(-W#pragma-messages)
```

is interpreted as:

```
add_definitions(-W
```

How is one supposed to be using this flag in a cmake script?

Comment: Did you already tried to enclose the argument in quotes, i.e. `add_definitions("-W#pragma-messages")`

Comment: It works! I didn't know you could enclose the options, and it also seems awkward to include the hash sign in a compiler option...
Anyway please post the comment as reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake everything following a `#` character until the end of line is treated as a comment.

To prevent this behaviour for your compile definitions and options you need to quote the entire argument

```
add_definitions("-W#pragma-messages")
```